# Normalizing unicode in dataset

Tags: python, unicode, normalize

Currently my code is the following:

```
import unicodedata
unicode = open("unicode.txt").read()
unicode = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', unicode)
print(unicode)
```

where `unicode.txt` is a text file that simply reads `\u00e9`.

When I run the program, the output is still `\u00e9`, however, if I replace `unicode` in the .normalize line with `\u00e9` the output is `é`.

The end goal is simply to replace all unicode strings (eg. \u00e9) with their regular characters. Like `cafe` instead of `café`.

**The normalize function seems to work fine when the string is entered into the function but not when it is in a file to be opened.** Even then it seems to return the stylized `é` instead of the regular `e`.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I'm not quite sure: which conversion are you after? a) `\u00e9` → `é`, b) `é` → `e`, c) `\u00e9` → `e`? Mark's answer helps you with a). Conversion b) is called transliteration (not normalization), and the `unidecode` package can help you. For c), combine a) and b).

Answer (score 1):

The content of the file is literally six characters: `\u0029`.  `'\u0029'` typed in code is a single Unicode code point represented as an escape code:

```
>>> print('\u00e9')   # A single character escape code
é
>>> print(r'\u0039')  # A six-character string using raw string notation.
\u0039                # Escape codes are ignored and characters are literal.
>>> print('\\u0039')  # A six-character string using an escaped backslash
\u0039                # to indicate a literal backslash.
```

To convert the six-character string to a character, use the following,

```
>>> r'\u00e9'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
'é'
```

The `ascii` encode is needed to translate a Unicode string of ASCII characters to a byte string because you can only decode byte strings in Python 3.  Python 2 can skip it as it implicitly encodes Unicode strings back to ASCII if needed.
You can also directly read it from the file (assuming Python 3), with:

```
with open('unicode.txt',encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Use `import io` and `io.open` on Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can change it to be readline() or readlines().
The code would be:

```
import unicodedata
unicode = open("unicode.txt", 'r')
for ln in unicode.readlines():
    ln = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', ln)
    print(ln)
```

The reason is because read() would treat each character in the file separately, meaning that the iteration would happen for every character. Meanwhile, readline or readlines() would treat the iteration for a line or the whole lines.

However, unicodedata tries to normalize the unicode in the string not as per character. Hope that would help.

References:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-differences-between-readline-and-readlines-in-selenium-with-python
https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/what-is-difference-between-read-and-readlines-in-python/478934